# Confusion with k-fold cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

I did k-fold CV on some data, but there is something which is confusing me which I don't really understand. I read in a book that for e.g. 3-fold cv I have to do 3 iterations so I will get 3 $MSE$'s. My mentor told me I can iterate many times and get many $MSE$'s. I briefly describe here how I understand it and how he told me I should do it:

For 3 iterations
I shuffle the data and I split the data into e.g. 3-folds.

1. In the test fold I calculate $MSE_1$.
2. Again I shuffle the data and calculate $MSE_2$ on the test data.
3. Again I shuffle the data and calculate $MSE_3$ on the test data.

I calculate the CV error by averaging the $MSE_1, MSE_2, MSE_3$.

How my mentor told me I should do CV:

For $n$ iterations e.g. $n=100$

1. I shuffle the data and I split the data into 3 folds and In the test fold I calculate $MSE_1$.
2. Again I shuffle the data and calculate $MSE_2$ on the test data.
3. ...

100.. Again I shuffle the data and calculate $MSE_{100}$ on the test data.

I calculate the CV error by adding $MSE_1,MSE_2,... MSE_n$ and dividing them by the number of folds,3.

I would very much appreciate any clarification.

Comment: You are just doing well, except that you must shuffle the data once, not three times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the confusion arises from the term "iterations".

Here's the process in the terminology I'm familiar with:

3-fold CV:

1. shuffle data
2. split into k = 3 segments (aka folds)
3. for each fold: calculate surrogate model without the fold in question and test the cases of the left-out fold.
4. after all k = 3 folds are done, calculate MSE as average squared error over all cases (= of all 3 folds).

Iterated k-fold CV (aka repeated k-fold CV) repeats/iterates that whole process 1. - 4. e.g. 100 times. You then have 100 MSEs, each of them calculated on all cases. (Only difference is that the surrogate models were trained with slightly different training sets).

---

Unfortunately, there's a whole lot of confusion about terminology for various flavors of cross validation. For the moment, I recommend to always describe in detail what you did.

---

I've met your procedures that shuffle freshly for each surrogate model under the name of set validation. In your case with 1/3 of all cases set aside for testing, and yes, also that procedure can be iterated or repeated - whether you do 3 or 100 repetitions is up to you, but there's no connection (unlike in k-fold CV) between the fraction of cases reserved for testing and the number of repetitions (aka iterations).

Comment: ok now I understand it, I actually thought that the number of repetitions(eka iterations) is connected with the number of folds. I have still a small question, after I get the 100 MSEs, and I want to calculate the CV-error should then I sum all the 100 MSEs and divide them by 3 ? Based on this formula : $CV_{(k)}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}MSE_i$ where my number of folds=3

Comment: Usually not. The usual way of calculating MSE is the average over all *cases* (i.e. if your folds have slightly varying numbers of cases e.g. due to rounding, you'd need to weight the fold-MSEs).

Comment: "*Unfortunately, there's a whole lot of confusion about terminology for various flavors of cross validation.*" True story. (+1 obviously)